# Entity Framework Migrations NuGet Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

Using Visual Studio 2013 Express Preview for Web and Entity Framework 5

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to enable migrations:

> PM> Enable-Migrations System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project
>   project)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project
>   project)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project
>   project)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String
>   configurationTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String
>   contextTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c_*DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   PM>

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried RC that shipped last week? You can get the RC from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads

Comment: I created a work item to verify this - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1658 but it is most likely fixed in RC. See https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/467 for more details.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same exact issue and finally solved it by installing "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell Redistributable Package (isolated)" (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30670).

Answer (score 5):

I tried the Redistributable Package mentioned earlier and it did not fix the error. Simply updating the Entity Framework through the NuGet Package Manager did the trick for me.

Comment: this worked for me too.  And I also tried installing the isolated shell pkg to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is also explained here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805933/filenotfoundexception-enabling-ef-migration

It says it is fixed with vs2013 update 2. But I just tested it with windows 8.1 and update 2 but could still reproduce this.